# Using two instance of maven in one desktop

Tags: maven

My pc is broken and I need to finish my project on my business laptop where maven is configured for business purposes. Is there any way to have two maven instances with different properties, paths ect. without interfering one to other? Is this save solution ?

Comment: What do you mean by `two maven instances`? You install maven into a particular path which you can add to `PATH` and then you use that one...if you like to use an other installed version change the `PATH` accordingly and that's it...Only the path like `apache-maven-3.2.5/bin` must be in `PATH` ...Of course you need to set JAVA_HOME correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-s` flag to specify a different `settings.xml` file when running mvn on the command line.  Make sure the alternative `settings.xml` file points to a separate .m2 directory.

I.E. `mvn clean install -s altSettings.xml`